# removing border/box in pslegend

Tags: pstricks, legend

I have the following MWE, where a `pslegend` is added to the plot. However, is there a way to remove the border? Or does this simply mean that I have to manually place each item using `rput`?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=32pt, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}[ysubticks=9, xsubticks=0, axesstyle=frame, ylogBase=10, logLines=all,ticksize=0 5pt, Dx=10, Ox={0}, Oy={0}](0,-10)(80,-4){7.0cm}{6.0cm}%
\pstScalePoints(1,1){  }{ log }

   \pslegend[rt](93,9){%
     \makebox[2em][l]{\psline[linecolor=black,  linestyle=dashed](0,1ex)(2em,1ex)}            & $f(x)$ \\
   \makebox[2.1em][c]{\psdot[dotstyle=*](0,0.7ex)}          & $t_1$}


\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine the style:

```
\newpsstyle{legendstyle}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none}
\begin{psgraph}[ysubticks=9, xsubticks=0, axesstyle=frame, ylogBase=10, 
               logLines=all,ticksize=0 5pt, Dx=10, Ox={0}, Oy={0}]%
     (0,-10)(80,-4){7.0cm}{6.0cm}%
```